# How to make Thymeleaf to process URL expressions in HTML comments

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I've started to use Thymeleaf and came across following problem.
In my HTML template I have this piece of code:

```
  <!-- Thymeleaf -->
  <script src="../js/vendor/modernizr.js" th:src="@{js/vendor/modernizr.js}"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-1.11.min.js" th:src="@{js/vendor/jquery-1.11.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="../js/helpers/polyfills.js" th:src="@{js/helpers/polyfills.js}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

When I open this in a browser, Thymeleaf is replacing URLs correctly for the first line, while for the part in [if lt IE 9], nothing is processed. Please compare:

```
<!-- Thymeleaf -->
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../js/vendor/jquery-1.11.min.js" th:src="@{js/vendor/jquery-1.11.min.js}"></script>
        <script src="../js/helpers/polyfills.js" th:src="@{js/helpers/polyfills.js}"></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the [Conditional Comments Extras Dialect](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments).

You just add `org.thymeleaf.extras.conditionalcomments.dialect.ConditionalCommentsDialect` to your template engine and it will work out of the box!

Comment: I've actually found the same solution today and it works like a charm. For adding dialect to template engine this page is very useful:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3

as it shows example configuration, which I actually had done beforehand.

Comment: Works great on Thymeleaf `2.1.5.RELEASE`. Tks @tom-verelst

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.attoparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>attoparser</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-conditionalcomments</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then add the followin lines in one of your Configuration code

```
@Bean
public ConditionalCommentsDialect conditionalCommentDialect() {
    return new ConditionalCommentsDialect();
}
```

This worked for me.